# How do I add the log message cumulativly into the java for each revision after it's been committed using RAD? --SVN

Tags: java, svn

I am trying to add Commit Comment messages at end of the Java source file to keep track about the file revision whenever we commit the file to SVN.

Please let me know the syntax. I tried with $Log$: it is not working. one of my projects in the earlier date i remember i used. I don't whether it is Server specific.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that. Really. SVN is there and has all the history of the file. And it's able to handle branches, which this strategy won't be able to handle.

It's not supported by SVN, for good reasons, explained here: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#log-in-source